# Error connect Visual Studio Code - ForceCode (Extension)

Tags: visualstudiocode

I have been using VisualStuio without problems, but today it does not allow me to connect to my sandbox. I can't do Retrieve or Save (I used the Developer Console again).
Do you know what can happen?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ETIMEDOUT` is a [network error](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html). It is more likely that this has to do with changes in your local network environment, such as firewalls, proxies, or overall connectivity through your ISP, than with Salesforce.

Comment: Yeahh, it was an internet connection problem. this week has worked correctly